# Knights and knaves on a square grid

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, puzzle

Today Gathering For Gardner [posted a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rL5MmCrEeIk) by Yoshiyuki Kotani called "Liar/Truth Teller Patterns on Square Planes".

The idea is that you fill a grid with knights and knaves so that both the knights and knaves can say "I am horizontally/vertically adjacent to $k$ knaves"—naturally the knights are telling the truth, and the knaves are lying.

## Examples

For all of these examples, let $k=1$ and let `.` represent a knight and `x` represent a knave.

For $k=1$, the "boring" solutions are those that consist of horizontal or vertical strips, such as

```
x x . . x x .
x x . . x x .
x x . . x x .
x x . . x x .
x x . . x x .
x x . . x x .
x x . . x x .
```

Here is a non-boring solution on a $4 \times 4$ grid.

```
. x . .
. . . x
x . . .
. . x .
```

Similarly the video claims that there is exactly one non-boring solution for a $5 \times 5$ grid up to symmetry of the square:

```
. . x . .
x . . . x
. . . . .
. x x x .
. x x x .
```

## Question

The video claims that there may be no solution for $k=1$ on the $6 \times 6$ board. That is, all of the solutions consist of horizontal/vertical strips. Is this the case? Is there a way to prove it?

Also, are there any corresponding OEIS sequences?

Comment: Did the video claim that the ***may*** be no solution in the $6 \times 6$ case, or that there ***is*** no solution in the $6 \times 6$ case?

Comment: [There may be no solution for $6\times6$.](https://youtu.be/rL5MmCrEeIk?t=100)

Comment: I suppose a 6x6 board full of knaves is boring? :)

Comment: I just brute-forced it (start in corner: Knight or Knave ... move to adjacent square: Knight or Knave ... etc. ... and of course making forced moves) I can confirm that there is indeed no non-boring solution for 6x6 ... but the space of the Comment is too small for an actual proof :) (but it is not ridiculously big either ... my search tree ended up with 42 nodes)

Comment: @Bram28, add your work as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @PeterKagey It's still 42 nodes ... times a 6x6 board ... not sure when I'll have the time :(